# How To customize different rows in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a page in iphone sdk which looks same as flight search result
problem is that each there are different number of stops some has 2 stops some has 1 etc. and not only leave flight detail but return flight detail can also be asked.
It must sorted on the basis of charges.

I am not getting from where I start

I make 3 custom cells

1. showing source n destination detail
2. the flight detail
3. to make separator between leave n return results

this is demo i have tried with fixed value! [1 row a SimpleTableIdentifier(background color not able to set) 2 and 3 row are 2 different CustemCell, there is separator custom cell too]
but I think i make it complex unnecessary
any tips and help will be apprecited thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to forget to give all different custom cells other dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier's for re-usability.

Answer (score 3):

Go like this make three customCell one for each of your three category

1. cell structure to show source and destination detail
2. cell structure to show flight detail
3. cell structure to make seperator

Now your `UITableView` will be a grouped tableView with `numberOfSections` = `number to total flight you have to show`

Each section will have three rows (if it has all three information available) else you can reduce the number of rows in any section by delegate method of `UITableView` named `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Above cells repeats for each records so I use tableview
so for this will UIScrollview helps?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem ... forget about UIScrollView